# Get entity value by Foreign key

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have Property entity with those properties

```
public class Property : FullAuditedEntity, IMustHaveTenant, IMustHaveAddresses<PropertyAddress>
{
    [Required]
    public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
    public virtual string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual int TenantId { get; set; }
    public virtual int? AgentId { get; set; }
    public virtual long? AccountManagerId { get; set; }

    public virtual int PropertyTitleId { get; set; }
    public virtual int BuildingTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual int? LandlordId { get; set; }
    public virtual int PropertyTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Attachments { get; set; }
    public virtual int? PortfolioId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("LandlordId")]
    public virtual Landlord Landlord { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AccountManagerId")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AgentId")]
    public virtual Agent Agent { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PropertyTitleId")]
    public virtual PropertyTitle PropertyTitle { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("BuildingTypeId")]
    public virtual BuildingType BuildingType { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PropertyTypeId")]
    public virtual PropertyType PropertyType { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PortfolioId")]
    public virtual LandlordPropertyPortfolio PropertyPortfolio { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PropertyAddress> Addresses { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PropertyAsset> PropertyAssets { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Site> Sites { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tenancy> Tenancies { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Utility> Utilities { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Quote> Quotes { get; set; }
}
```

It has a collection of Tenancies

Here is Tenancy entity

```
 public class Tenancy : FullAuditedEntity, IMustHaveTenant
{
    public DateTime? TenancyStartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? TenancyEndDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? RenewalDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ContractEndDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ReminderNotificationDate { get; set; }
    public ContractTermTimeUnit ContractTermTimeUnit { get; set; }
    public int ContractTermLength { get; set; }
    public TenancyStatus Status { get; set; }
    public int PropertyTenantId { get; set; }
    public int PropertyId { get; set; }
    public int ContractTypeId { get; set; }
    public int TenantId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ContractTypeId")]
    public ContractType ContractType { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PropertyId")]
    public Property Property { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PropertyTenantId")]
    public PropertyTenant PropertyTenant { get; set; }


}
```

Tenancy connected to PropertyTenant via ForeignKey

Here is PropertyTenant entity

```
 public class PropertyTenant: FullAuditedEntity, IMustHaveTenant
{
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual string MobileNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual string LinkedinUrl { get; set; }
    public virtual string FacebookUrl { get; set; }
    public virtual string TwitterUrl { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsPhonePreferred { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsMobilePreferred { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsEmailPreferred { get; set; }
    public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
    public virtual int TenantId { get; set; }
    public string IdentifierString  { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tenancies.Tenancy> Tenancies { get; set; }
    public virtual  ICollection<Quote> Quotes { get; set; }
}
```

I need to get all properties, passing to method PropertyTenantId

Here is method code, that I was trying to do

```
   public async Task<ListResultDto<DropdownOptionDto>> GetPropertySuggestions(string address, int? customerType,
            int? customerId)
        {
            IQueryable<Property> query = null;
            if (customerType == 3)
            {
                query = _propertyRepository.GetAll().WhereIf(!address.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(),
                    p => p.Addresses.First().Line1.StartsWith(address.Trim(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
                         p.AgentId == customerId);
            }

            if (customerType == 1)
            {
                query = _propertyRepository.GetAll().WhereIf(!address.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(),
                    p => p.Addresses.First().Line1.StartsWith(address.Trim(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
                         p.LandlordId == customerId);
            }

            if (customerType == 2)
            {

                query = _propertyRepository.GetAll().WhereIf(!address.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(),
                    p => p.Addresses.First().Line1.StartsWith(address.Trim(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
                         p.Tenancies.Where(i => i.PropertyTenantId == customerId));

            }
```

I customer type =2 I cannot get properties because of

> PropertyAppService.cs(186, 26): [CS0019] Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'IEnumerable'

How I can get all properties via PropertyTenantId?

Comment: well error is self explanatory - `p.Tenancies.Where(i => i.PropertyTenantId == customerId)` returns `IEnumerable` so cannot be used in a `Where`... Maybe should be `Any`?

Comment: At least now I don't have error. Will try. Thanks @VidmantasBlazevicius